# Mule: Exception Handling in File transfer Mule flow

Tags: mule

I have a simplistic mule configuration that takes in HTTP Query parameters, builds a URL & downloads a File from the URL. It does nothing much & does not use any kind of File (or FTP/SFTP) protocols. What kind of Exception handling mechanism do I need to think about for this?

Here is the snippet of code:

```
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8048" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
 <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="${sync.host}" port="${sync.port}" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
 <file:connector name="output" doc:name="File"/>


 <flow name="syncFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/og" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-variable variableName="year" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.year]" doc:name="Variable"/>     
    <set-variable variableName="month" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.month]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path= "/year/{year}/month/{month}/monthly.csv" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">   
       <http:request-builder>
          <http:uri-param paramName="year" value="#[flowVars.year]"/> 
          <http:uri-param paramName="month" value="#[flowVars.month]"/>
       </http:request-builder> 
    </http:request>
```

Also this is the end of the flow & I just simply dump the file I receive , any suggestions on elegant ways of handling this part of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What kind of Exception handling mechanism do I need to think about for
>   this?

I would use a choice exception strategy to catch, at a minimum, exceptions related to file permissions, disk space, and an already existing file.

> any suggestions on elegant ways of handling this part of the code?

I would probably remove the variable declarations if you're not going to be re-using them and just put the values directly in the request builder. You can also collapse those into one "Message Properties" transformer using the invocation scope.

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of Exception handling mechanism do I need to think about for
>   this?

You can have a `Rollback Exception Strategy` in case the service you are sending the request to is down or fails to receive your request properly.